# Timeout exception error when copy from azure sql to azure sql of data have only 300000 rows

Tags: sql, azure, timeout, azure-sql-database

`Azure sql` *Timeout exception error* only when i try to copy from azure sql to azure sql data bigger or equal to 300000 rows

Answer (score 1):

Increase the DB's DTU. So it should solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

So when the data size is big then we can use stored procedure for copying the data

Comment: Hi @Ashim, let's not use reply as comments. You can comment down each suggestion like I'm doing here. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should increase your command timeout, set it based on your service objective

Comment: how to increase that in Azure SQL Database?